# Java - Varied amount of input data- specific format of output

Tags: java

Instructions;

> Statistics are often calculated with varying amounts of input data. Write a program that takes any number of non-negative integers as input, and outputs the max and average. A negative integer ends the input and is not included in the statistics. Assume the input contains at least one non-negative integer.
>
> Output the average with two digits after the decimal point followed by a newline, which can be achieved as follows:
> `System.out.printf("%.2f\n", average);`
>
> Ex: When the input is:
> `15 20 0 3 -1`
> the output is:
> `20 9.50`

I have tried a few different ways to convert the int avg into a string but somehow keep messing up.. What am I not doing?? Example code below

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner scnr = new Scanner (System.in);
      int num = 0;
      int count = 0;
      int max = 0;
      int total = 0;
      int avg = 0;
      String s=Integer.toString(avg);

     do {

         total += num;
         num = scnr.nextInt();
         count = ++count;


         if (num >= max) {
            max = num;
         }

      } while (num >= 0);

     avg = total/(count-1);

      System.out.printf("%.2f\n", avg);


   }
}
```

Comment: `avg` is an `int` and the `%f` specifier is for `float`. You can change `int avg = 0;` to `float avg = 0;` and don't forget to change to `avg = (float)total / (count-1);` otherwise you will have integer division.

Comment: Side note: if the user only enters a single negative number then `avg = total/(count-1);` will result in a divide by zero exception.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is almost correct. The only things, you would need to change for this to work are these:

```
int avg = 0; // The type of avg should be a float
```

The reason for this is that what you're printing is a float but before these changes, you are providing it with an int.

```
// The number you are providing avg with should be cast to a float value
avg = total/(count-1);
```

This is because if you didn't, you would have integer division.

```
// It would look like this
float avg = 0;

avg = (float)total/(count-1);
```